# How to find the intersection of 2 arrays with case insensitive?

Tags: php

I want to find the intersection between 2 array.

- $valid
- $polish

I use `array_intersect` and store the return value in `$perfect` variable.

`$perfect = array_intersect( $valid, $polish );`

So far so good, except one thing, I want `array_intersect` to ignore the case sensitive between both array.

What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Lowercase the elements of both before comparing them.

Comment: Sound like a good idea, let me try.

Comment: How about `array_uintersect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i just put all values to lower case with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php))

```
$perfect = array_intersect(array_map("strtolower", $valid), array_map("strtolower", $polish));
```

Comment: Precise answer ! 100% working ! thank-you [@Rizier123](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strcasecmp()` (case-insensitive string comparison) as a callback using `array_uintersect()`:

```
$perfect = array_uintersect($valid, $polish, 'strcasecmp');
```

Comment: Some would say, "The Solution".